# How can you manage ACL with Vue-Router?

Tags: vue-router

Specifically what I want to do is to render messages like 403 instead of what was supposed to be viewed, or to automatically set Vue-Router to change components while keeping the same url.
So what are the best practices for managing User Access Levels/Roles/Lists with Vue-Router? How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article about acl integration in Vue2 - https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/vue-acl-with-casl-781a374b987a

For router integration the only thing which you need to do is to check permissions in router.beforeEach callback

Alternatively just don't render links and buttons which can't be accessed by specific user and in case when user navigates to forbidden page API will return 403, you can  intercept all HTTP requests (in axios) and route user to a different page.

I prefer the latest approach because it doesn't add additional complexity to router/routes and behaves properly when use try to navigate directly to forbidden URL